# Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What is this error?

> Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    SubmitApplication::where('id', $request->get(id))->update(['approved' => true]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: This typo question doesn't need to exist on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Strings need to be wrapped in quotes, otherwise PHP assumes it's a name of a constant, hence the error.

Replace

```
$request->get(id)
```

with

```
$request->get('id')
```